# How to switch session role securely?

Tags: postgresql, security, role

I'd like to setup a service through which my users can submit SQL queries to a database wherein I store some data. Users are assigned to organizations, and I've setup views that provide read access only to rows that belong to a given organization, and roles that have `SELECT` on those views.

I'd like to not have to manage a ton of usernames and passwords. Instead, my plan was to connect to the DB as a more privileged role, and before executing a query, run `SET SESSION ROLE <relevant_organization_role>` and then execute the user's query.

However, in testing, it seems like it's possible for the user to just `RESET ROLE` and then run their query as the more privileged role, which is a non-starter.

I tried using [`SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-set-session-authorization.html), but the docs say

> The session user identifier can be changed only if the initial session user (the authenticated user) had the superuser privilege.

And I'd rather not use a superuser role for the initial connection. Plus, when I've tested this approach in my client, it lets me `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION DEFAULT` afterwards and return to the superuser role -- and I definitely don't want to risk that.

[The PostreSQL GRANT docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-grant.html) say

> [A role] may grant or revoke membership in itself from a database session where the session user matches the role.

I take that to suggest that I should be able to do something like

```
-- from a connection to the "service" role

SET SESSION ROLE tenant_1; -- switch to a new role
REVOKE SESSION ROLE service; -- prevent subsequent use of the "service" role

-- use this connection to execute queries as "tenant_1" without being able to use RESET ROLE to restore the "service" role privileges
```

But the only information I can really find on session roles is [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-set-role.html) which doesn't have any info on *revoking* a role from a session.

Is it possible to revoke a role from a session, such that the rest of the session *has* to run in a more restricted role?

Or do I just have to be prepared to manage a whole bunch of username + password pairs?

Or is there some other way to accomplish what I'm trying?

Comment: The [`set_user` extension](https://github.com/pgaudit/set_user) looks like it might help